# clear inputed data after ajaxsubmit and updating clistview

Tags: yii

in views index.php i have

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'id'=>"post_list",
    )); 
 ?>
 <div id="addtodo">
   <?php $this->renderPartial('ajax_page', array('model' => $model, ));?>
 </div>
```

and in ajax_page.php

```
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
      'id'=>'post-todo',
      'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

 <?php
 echo $form->textFieldRow(
    $model,
    'title',
    array(
        'class' => 'input-medium span6 addtodo',
        'placeholder'=>'New todo task',
        'prepend' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>',
    )
);
?>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton ("Post",
            CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('todo/add')),
            array("success"=>'js:function(data){$.fn.yiiListView.update("post_list",{});}'),
            array('class'=>'')
            ); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

So, All work fine. but after updating CListview, inputed text keeping in input form . 
How to clear input form after updating CListview with Ajax?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the javascript [.reset() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp). You will need to change your ajax button to this;

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton ("Post",
            CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('todo/add')),
            array("success"=>'js:function(data){
                $.fn.yiiListView.update("post_list",{});
                $("#post-todo")[0].reset();
            }'),
            array('class'=>'')
            ); ?>
```